# How make images completely wrap around image view with google card view

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I have been tring to get a seamless looking card view but each image does not completely wrap around the image view. Is there a particular resolution I need to achieve this or can this be done in the xml. The pictures should also look the same in landscape and portrait.
Here is an example of what I am talking about. [Google card view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4bWX.png)

Comment: did you try adding android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: an where is the example of your results and your xml?

Comment: please add some code or xml layout here

Answer (score 0):

Add android:scaleType="fitXY" in your imageview